# If a subset of bounded continuous functions is separating for the class of probaiblity measures, is it already separable for finite signed measures?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a metric space and $\mathcal M(E)$ denote the set of finite signed measures on $(E,\mathcal B(E))$. Remember that $\mathcal C\subseteq C_b(E)$ is called *separating* for $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathcal M(E)$ if $$\forall\mu,\nu\in\mathcal F:\left(\forall f\in\mathcal C:\int f\:{\rm d}(\mu-\nu)=0\right)\Rightarrow\mu=\nu\tag1.$$

Let $\mathcal M_+(E)$ and $\mathcal M_1(E)$ denote the set of finite and probability measures on $(E,\mathcal E)$, respectively.

> If $\mathcal C$ is separating for $\mathcal M_1(E)$, does it already follow that $\mathcal C$ is separating for $\mathcal M(E)$?

I'm not sure whether I'm missing something or not, but I think this should be true, since every finite signed measures can be written as a difference of two finite measures and every nontrivial finite measure can be normalized to a probability measure.

Answer (score 0):

True if the constant function $1$ belongs to $\mathcal C$. In this case $\int f d(\mu-\nu)=0$ for all $f \in \mathcal C$ implies $\mu=\nu$ even $\mu ,\nu$ are just positive finite measures (not necessarily probability measures). [This is because $\mu (E)=\nu (E)$].

Suppose $\int fd(\mu-\nu)=0$ for all $f \in \mathcal C$. Write $\mu=\mu_1-\mu_2, \nu=\nu_1-\nu_2$ where $\mu_1,\mu_2,\nu_1,\nu_2$ are finite positive measures. Then $\int fd((\mu_1+\nu_2)-(\mu_2+\nu_1))=0$. It follows that $\mu_1+\nu_2=\mu_2+\nu_1$ from which we get $\mu=\nu$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. At which point did you need that $1\in\mathcal C$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d That was to conclude that $\mu(E) = \nu(E)$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d To go from probability measures to finite measures you have to divide the equation $\int f d(\mu-\nu)=0$ by a constant. So we want to make $\mu$ and $\nu$ probability measures simultaneously and that requires $\mu (E)=\nu(E)$. If $1 \in \mathcal C$ then $\int 1 d(\mu-\nu)=0$ which gives us $\mu (E)=\nu (E)$ so the equation can be divided by the constant  $\mu (E)=\nu (E)$.